# How to add "babel-preset-stage-2" loader to a rails/webpacker/vue app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, babeljs, webpacker

I have a rails 5 app and I installed vue with the command rails webpacker:install:vue. I just need to add the "babel-preset-stage-2" loader but I can't figure out how to do that.

I read [this documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#loaders) and here's what I did (but it doesn't work) in config/webpack/loaders/vue.js:

```
const { dev_server: devServer } = require('@rails/webpacker').config

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const inDevServer = process.argv.find(v => v.includes('webpack-dev-server'))
const extractCSS = !(inDevServer && (devServer && devServer.hmr)) || isProduction

module.exports = {
  test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: { extractCSS }
  }]
}

module.exports = {
  test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-preset-stage-2'
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've included 2 module.exports, which is not how commonJS modules work. If you read the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/), you should be able to do something like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: { extractCSS }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
        loader: 'babel-preset-stage-2'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```